# How does one Determine the Number of Factorizations of a Natural Number?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

For any given number n $\in N$, how would I find the number of factorizations of n? For example, the number 8 has three combinations* of factorizations ($2^3, 2^2\cdot2,$ and $2\cdot2\cdot2$) so we can say the Factor Combination function $FC(8) = 3$. How would I find $FC(n)$ for an arbitrary $n$?

By the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, every number can be expressed as a unique prime factorization in the form $p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdotp_2^{\alpha_2}\cdot...p_n^{\alpha_n}$. I know that the $FC(n)$ doesn't depend on the particular prime factors, but only on the different $\alpha$'s (e.g. $FC(5^3) = FC(2^3) = FC(p^3) = 3$, for any arbitrary prime $p$.

*My application doesn't care about order, so I would like to find combinations instead of permutations. If it helps, I am trying to find the number of Abelian groups of a given order up to isomorphsim.

Comment: You may need to use [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) for the exponents of each prime and then combine them.

Comment: If we have the prime factorization, this is straight forward.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230960/asymptotics-for-the-number-of-abelian-groups-of-order-at-most-x

Comment: @Peter, I know how to find the prime factorization for any given number. How can I leverage that to find all of the factorizations?

Comment: @Peter If you are only looking for the number of ways to write it as a product of 2 numbers, then it is essentially just finding the number of divisors and this is easy. Here however it is about the number of factorizations into any number of factors, ignoring order.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I know, therefore I called the solution "straight forward" anot not "easy" or even "trivial".

Comment: @Jafego I don't think factorizations is exactly what you need to be counting. For example, 30=2*3*5=2*15=3*10=5*6 but there is only one group of order 30, the cyclic group. But the number of Abelian groups is a multiplicative function, so you do have NA(30)=NA(2)*NA(3)*NA(5)=1*1*1=1.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis thank you for your clarification. The mod linked to a post that answered the question I should have been asking.